# Deleting a Location with Acumatica API

Tags: acumatica

I would like to Delete one of a customer's Location records.  I've never deleted anything before, and I don't see any examples of that on StackOverflow or in Acumatica's provided examples.  It seems like doing a Submit with the key fields and the Delete command would make sense, but this is giving me a pretty vague "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." error.  Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here, or if this is the wrong approach all together?  Code and full error message below.

```
Public Function DeleteLocation(ByVal customerID As String, ByVal locID As String) As Boolean
    Dim address As CR303010Content = m_context.CR303010GetSchema()
    m_context.CR303010Clear()

    Dim customerVal As New Value() With {.LinkedCommand = address.LocationSummary.Customer, .Value = customerID}
    Dim idVal As New Value() With {.LinkedCommand = address.LocationSummary.LocationID, .Value = locID}

    ' execute delete
    Dim deleteCommands As Command() = {customerVal, idVal, address.Actions.Delete}
    Dim deleteResult As CR303010Content() = m_context.CR303010Submit(deleteCommands)

    Return True

End Function
```

Throws this exception:

```
System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> 
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at PX.Objects.CR.LocationMaintBase`3.Location_RowDeleted(PXCache cache, PXRowDeletedEventArgs e)
at PX.Data.PXCache.OnRowDeleted(Object item, Boolean externalCall)
at PX.Data.PXCache`1.Delete(Object data, Boolean bypassinterceptor)
at PX.Data.PXCache`1.Delete(Object data, Boolean bypassinterceptor)
at PX.Data.PXCache`1.Delete(Object data)
at PX.Data.PXDelete`1.<Handler>d__0.MoveNext()
at PX.Data.PXAction`1.<Press>d__c.MoveNext()
at PX.Data.PXAction`1.<Press>d__c.MoveNext()
at PX.Api.SyImportProcessor.SyStep.CommitChanges(Object itemToBypass, PXFilterRow[] targetConditions)
at PX.Api.SyImportProcessor.ExportTableHelper.ExportTable()
at PX.Api.ScreenUtils.Submit(String screenId, Command[] commands, SchemaMode schemaMode, PXGraph graph)
at PX.Api.Services.ScreenService.Submit(String id, IEnumerable`1 commands, SchemaMode schemaMode)
at PX.Api.Soap.Screen.ScreenGate.Submit(Command[] commands)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

Comment: This looks like a bug in the application, your code is clean. Does the location you're trying to delete has a valid address and contact? I checked the code for Location_RowDeleted and it's where I see we could have NullReferenceException...

Comment: @Gabriel For the address I'm trying to delete, the Contact is set to "Same as Main" and the address is set to a valid address with all fields filled in except Address Line 2.  Thanks for checking your Location_RowDeleted, please let me know if you find that is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct, but it fails when deleting a location which doesn't use the default address or contact info. This is due to a bug affecting all versions of Acumatica. The workaround is to re-check "Use Default" before deleting the location. The issue has been reported and is currently being fixed. Thanks for your help Eric in troubleshooting this problem, and sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

I can propose you ugly way: PXDatabase.Delete. It will generate delete statement directly in db. For example in C#:

PXDatabase.Delete(new PXDataFieldRestrict("RefNbr", row.APRefNbr), new PXDataFieldRestrict("DocType", "INV"));
                                PXDatabase.Delete(new PXDataFieldRestrict("RefNbr", row.APRefNbr), new PXDataFieldRestrict("DocType", "INV"));

Comment: Using the Web Services API, I don't believe I have access to the PXDatabase object and commands.  I only have access to screens/objects that were in the generated WSDL file.  But please let me know if I'm wrong, I'd be happy to use PXDatabase.Delete if I can.

Comment: I propose  to try to make button which executes this action, and call that button

Comment: I think this is a very bad idea - you bypass all business logic.

Comment: That's why I wrote ugly way

Answer (score 0):

The code below works fine

```
            Content CR303010 = context.GetSchema();
        context.Clear();

        context.Submit(
            new Command[]
            {
                new Value { Value = "ABARTENDE", LinkedCommand = CR303010.LocationSummary.BusinessAccount, Commit = true },
                new Value { Value = "TEST2", LinkedCommand = CR303010.LocationSummary.LocationID, Commit = true },
                CR303010.Actions.Delete
            }
        );
```

Comment: for your first Value, your LinkedCommand is CR303010.LocationSummary.BusinessAccount . My CR303010.LocationSummary does not have a BusinessAccount property, which is why I'm using CR303010.LocationSummary.Cusotmer.  That and the Commit=true properties are the only differences I see between your code and mine.  I tried adding Commit=true for each value but I still received the same error.

Comment: i've used version 5.00.2718

Comment: That's interesting.  We're using Version 4.20.2063.  I will look into the possibility of upgrading.  It may be a while if we are even able to, but will let you know if that solves the issue

Comment: @EricBarr did you resolve the issue? we can look into it further if needed

Comment: @Gabriel No, I haven't.  It may be quite a while before we are able to try it on a new version.  If you have time to look into it further, that would be great, thank you.

Comment: @EricBarr please reach out to me via e-mail, it's in my profile (i'll respond from my Acumatica.com e-mail address)

Comment: @EricBarr I tested with your code and it worked fine for me here. I did have to make an adjustment for it to compile - this may be related to your problem. I don't have any field names address.LocationSummary.Customer, here it's address.LocationSummary.BusinessAccount. Reach out to me via e-mail, i'll try to help.